# Search is not a function error on Angular 2 Pipe Array Filter

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have Angular 2 Search Pipe that filters against an array... Like this...

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args?): Array<any> {
    let searchText = new RegExp(args, 'ig');
    if (value) {
      return value.filter(ocurrence => {
        if ( ocurrence.nroCasoDegir ) {
          return ocurrence.nroCasoDegir.search(searchText) !== -1;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

But I always get the follow error...

> ocurrence.nroCasoDegir.search is not a function

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What is `nroCasoDegir`?

Comment: Is an attribute of my array...

Answer (score 0):

This issue is just a typo, you meant `indexOf`not `search`.

Try with this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'SearchPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args?): Array<any> {
    let searchText = new RegExp(args, 'ig');
    if (value) {
      return value.filter(ocurrence => {
        if ( ocurrence.nroCasoDegir ) {
          return ocurrence.nroCasoDegir.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3238318 did you check this answer?